# What is the PHP equivalent of this JavaScript Regular Expression?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

```
return str.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\s,]/g, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return preg_replace('/[().\s,-]/', '', $str);
```

You don't need to escape all those characters in  a character class (neither in JavaScript nor PHP).

Answer (score 5):

```
return preg_replace('/[\(\)\.\-\s,]/', '', $str);
```

For what it's worth, most of those backslashes are unnecessary (in either language). Parentheses and dots do not need to be escaped inside of character classes. You could simplify that to this if you wish:

```
return preg_replace('/[().\-\s,]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: You can move the `-` to the end: `/[().\s,-]/`

Comment: @Felix Yes, you're right, although that toes the line between "clean" and "a bit too clever".

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\(\)\.\-\s,]/','',$string);
```

Simple as that.

Note: The modifier `g` in php does not exists

Comment: The modifier `g` does not exist in PHP PCRE: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php